# Memory Management: NSString's stringWithCString:encoding:

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management, core-foundation

Suppose I'm getting a C string from some function:

`char * mystring = SomeCFunction(...);`

And I own this string (I'm responsible for freeing it when I'm done).

If, in Objective-C, I create an `NSString *` using:

```
NSString * mynsstring = [NSString stringWithCString:mystring 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Am I still responsible for freeing the original C string?**

I'm assuming the answer is yes, but I can't find a definitive answer in the documentation - and the functionality of the opposite method (`cStringUsingEncoding`), while sensical, does give me pause, because it handles the cString freeing for you.

If the answer is yes, then am I also responsible for making sure I don't free the c string before I'm done using the `NSString *`, or does the function copy the string for me? I ask this because the documentation for `stringWithCString` says it:

> Returns a string containing the bytes in a given C array, interpreted
>   according to a given encoding.

Which still leaves me wondering if it actually copied the bytes, or is just pointing at them internally (and I'm basically just doing a cast).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does copy the bytes.

If you don't want the bytes to be copied, you may use `- (id)initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding freeWhenDone:(BOOL)flag` instead.

If you use `- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`, or any commodity method like `stringWithCString:encoding:` that itself calls this low-level method, the bytes are copied.

Comment: Ah! You're awesome. Thank you! I'll accept the answer after the 6 minutes remaining on the accept-blocking timer has expired.

Comment: @AndréFratelli I suggest you file a feedback (there is a link at the bottom of every page of the online documentation) so Apple adds this there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The API has no idea where the pointer you pass it comes from so it doesn't know how to take ownership of it. It could be from malloc(), but it could also be an interior pointer or from mmap(), in which case free() won't work. So the API is forced to copy the data.

The only time you can pass ownership of a C buffer to a Cocoa API is if the API allows you to tell it it needs freeing. Take a look at `-[NSData initWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:]`, for example.

Comment: +1, Yeah, that makes a lot of sense to me... sometimes I just with the Apple docs were a little bit more explicit about things like this - instead of leaving you to deduce those things for yourself. In this case it made me hesitate long enough that I figured I should ask.

Comment: Fair enough. File a bug and ask for this to be called out explicitly in the documentation.